# Table overflow on container div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

Im creating a React component that will display a table with certain headers, the main problem is that when the width of the table overflows the max width of the container div, it doesnt respect the property of overflow-x.
Im using tailwind to complement and i attached the full code of the component and an image to see more easily the problematic.

[Table overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWQbZ.png)

```
export const PlantServiceOrders = () => {
  return (
    <div className='w-full bg-white mb-6 shadow-lg rounded'>
      <div className='w-full p-4'>
        <h3>Ordenes de Servicio por completar</h3>
      </div>
      <div className='max-w-full overflow-x-scroll'>
        <table className='w-full border-collapse'>
          <thead>
            <tr className='[&>*]:px-6 [&>*]:bg-gray-100 [&>*]:text-gray-500 [&>*]:border [&>*]:border-solid [&>*]:border-gray-200 [&>*]:py-3 [&>*]:text-xs [&>*]:uppercase [&>*]:border-l-0 [&>*]:border-r-0 [&>*]:whitespace-no-wrap [&>*]:font-semibold [&>*]:text-center'>
              <th>folio</th>
              <th>planta</th>
              <th>cliente</th>
              <th>número parte</th>
              <th>nombre parte</th>
              <th>defecto</th>
              <th>contacto</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th>teléfono</th>
              <th>fecha inicio</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr className='hover:bg-gray-200 [&>*]:border-t-0 [&>*]:px-6 [&>*]:align-middle [&>*]:border-l-0 [&>*]:border-r-0 [&>*]:text-xs [&>*]:whitespace-no-wrap [&>*]:p-4'>
              <td>XXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XX XXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXX XX XXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXX XXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXX-XX-X </td>
              <td>
                <button className='text-white text-md bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 rounded-lg py-2 px-4 cursor-pointer font-semibold'>
                  Completar
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your problem properly, you expect the table to fit in the parent div without horizontal scroll.

The problem is, that by default browsers try to compute width of table columns automatically, based on the content. But if you want, you may define columns width in code. Read more about this on the [CSSWG website](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#width-layout).

With the TailwindCSS, you can add the `table-fixed` class to the table, according to [Table Layout Tailwind docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/table-layout). But don’t forget to add some width to the columns, e.g. with the [w-classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width). It may look like this:

```
export const PlantServiceOrders = () => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full bg-white mb-6 shadow-lg rounded">
      <div className="w-full p-4">
        <h3>Ordenes de Servicio por completar</h3>
      </div>
      <div className="max-w-full overflow-x-scroll">
        <table className="w-full table-fixed border-collapse">
          <thead className="text-left">
            <tr className="[&>*]:px-6 [&>*]:bg-gray-100 [&>*]:text-gray-500 [&>*]:border [&>*]:border-solid [&>*]:border-gray-200 [&>*]:py-3 [&>*]:text-xs [&>*]:uppercase [&>*]:border-l-0 [&>*]:border-r-0 [&>*]:whitespace-no-wrap [&>*]:font-semibold [&>*]:text-center">
              <th className="w-24">folio</th>
              <th className="w-16">planta</th>
              <th className="w-32">cliente</th>
              <th className="w-32">número parte</th>
              <th className="w-32">nombre parte</th>
              <th className="w-32">defecto</th>
              <th className="w-32">contacto</th>
              <th className="w-32">email</th>
              <th className="w-32">teléfono</th>
              <th className="w-24">fecha inicio</th>
              <th className="w-32"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody className="align-top break-words">
            <tr className="hover:bg-gray-200 [&>*]:border-t-0 [&>*]:px-6 [&>*]:align-middle [&>*]:border-l-0 [&>*]:border-r-0 [&>*]:text-xs [&>*]:whitespace-no-wrap [&>*]:p-4">
              <td>XXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX XXXXXX XXXX XX XXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXX XX XXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXX XXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX </td>
              <td>XXXXXXXXXX</td>
              <td>XXXX-XX-X </td>
              <td>
                <button className="text-white text-md bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 rounded-lg py-2 px-4 cursor-pointer font-semibold">
                  Completar
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```